# Как перевести милисекунды в нормальное для понимания время

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, время, qt4

Пишу небольшой плеер, используя QMediaPlayer. Есть сигнал, который срабатывает каждые 1000 миллисекунд.

Мне интересно, можно как-то перевести миллисекунды в нормальное время типа `2:23` (2 минуты двадцать три секунды), или нужно делать 2 виджета; один для минут, а второй для секунд?

Comment: Разделите на тысячу и будут секунды :)

Comment: @dIm0n да мне не проблема из милисекунд сделать минуты или секунды, просто интерестно, есть ли в qt некий функционал для отобажения человеческого времени?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20063540/13970074

Comment: @dIm0n да это оно, но это так скажем костыль. Мне просто интерестно, может есть подобный функционал в qt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь классом [QTime](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html) и, например, методом [QTime::addMSecs(int ms)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#addMSecs)

```
QTime time(0, 0);

time = time.addMSecs(1000);
qDebug() << time; // Вывод в формате hh:mm:ss.zzz QTime("00:00:01.000")

time = time.addMSecs(1000);
qDebug() << time; // QTime("00:00:02.000")

time = time.addSecs(650); // + 650 секунд
qDebug() << time; // QTime("00:10:52.000")

...
```

Если надо в своем формате, то используем метод [QTime::toString(const QString& format)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtime.html#toString)

```
qDebug() << time.toString("mm.ss"); // 00.02
qDebug() << time.toString("mm:ss"); // 00:02
```

Comment: А вот это именно оно. Спасибо.